# Varying accepted answer colors

Tags: feature-request, design, accepted-answer

Compare the two images below:

[image: Not accepted][image: Accepted][image: Checkmark]

The first image shows the box in the question list telling you how many answers there are and whether one is accepted on the question. The second is for the accepted answer's checkmark.

This accepted answer color change can also be seen across sites in the Stack Exchange network.

[image: Not accepted][image: Accepted][image: Checkmark]

The first image in this set is from Stack Overflow on its question list, and , is the second is for Stack Overflow on the question list, and the third is for Ask Different on the question list.

More red and blue is present in the Stack Overflow checkmark than the darker green found on the question list answer section. The unaccepted and accepted variants of the answer section have mostly the same color.

[image: Not accepted][image: Accepted][image: Checkmark]

The above is for Ask Different. Do you see any difference here?

Can we change the colors to match each other (or at least for the checkmark and the question list)?

Comment: There are a lot more than that—all graduated sites have different designs. It doesn't make sense to imply a color limitation on that one specific element and nothing else.

Comment: It's almost the same green.

Comment: Not across all sites.

Comment: Come check out [ubuntu.se]. It's a much more vibrant green. Why should they be the same? They're under the same network, but they're not the same site. Corporate chains have similar layouts, but none are exactly the same, just like with SE.

Comment: So what if it's not 100% the same? It's still green, and easily distinguishable from other colors and elements. I really don't think that there's any need to change anything.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder what problem this will fix. Why should the colors be the same? I don't see any reason to restrict the designers to use another green if it fits in the site design better.

Although the color difference isn't too much, the difference is very well noticeable when viewing the site (you can try changing the site colors if you'd like to). The green color used has been deliberately chosen since it fits the site design best. Let's not change that.

Comment: See my post edit. The checkmark has a huge difference from the question list green.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what problem changing it will fix @Peanut. You'll need to do at least that if you want this to be seriously considered

Answer (score 3):

You're taking these elements out of context. They all exist as part of larger site-dependant designs, and in the case of the answer count and checkmark aren't even seen on the same page.

Let's have a look at a few random examples, in context:

[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

[image: English Language & Usage Questions]

[image: English Language & Usage Accepted Answer]

[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)

[image: Science Fiction & Fantasy Questions]

[image: Science Fiction & Fantasy Accepted Answer]

[Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)

[image: Role-playing Games Questions]

[image: Role-playing Games Accepted Answer]

The color choices make much more sense when seen in context, as part of a larger site design.

The accepted answer indicator and checkmark are some of the main elements of a site's independent design and the color choices need to take in to account background colors, surroundings, context and much much more—imposing a specific and arbitrary color limitation on these elements for *every site on the network* makes little sense. There is no need for it and it would be detrimental.

If you have a specific case on a specific site where you believe the design should be changed then there is nothing wrong with bringing it up on *that site's meta*. But a blanket rule limiting every site on the network makes no sense.

Comment: Still, the checkmark and question list greens differ on the same site.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Why should they be the same color?

Comment: It makes more sense to do that.

Comment: I don't see why.